# Who is stabbed here?

Tags: literature, sentence-meaning

I'm not sure who is stabbed and who is snarling here.

" Ralf launched himself like a cat; stabbed, snarling, with the spear, and the savage doubled up."

Thanks in advance

Comment: The guy who doubled up. Because he was stabbed.

Comment: Ralf stabbed with the spear [while] snarling.

Comment: The use of that semicolon is ungrammatical. What follows it is not an independent clause nor is the semicolon being used to separate list items that contain commas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It certainly could be more clearly said, but I would read this as the "savage" has been stabbed, resulting in their "doubling up."  The actions "stabbed," and "snarling, with the spear," are a list of the things Ralf did after "launch(ing) himself like a cat."

Answer (score 0):

This is a quote from Chapter 12 of the novel "Lord of the Flies" by William Golding.

Here's some context from about 3 paragraphs before your quote:

> Ralph fastened his hands round the chewed spear and his hair fell. Someone was muttering, only a few yards away toward the Castle Rock. He heard a savage say "No!" in a shocked voice; and then there was suppressed laughter. He squatted back on his heels and showed his teeth at the wall of branches. He raise *[sic]* his spear, snarled a little, and waited.

Ralph attacks again at the time of your quote, about 3 paragraphs after this:

> A smallish savage was standing between him and the rest of the forest, a savage striped red and white, and carrying a spear. He was coughing and smearing the paint about his eyes with the back of his hand as he tried to see through the increasing smoke. Ralph launched himself like a cat; stabbed, snarling, with the spear, and the savage doubled up.

We can parse the word *snarling* in the last sentence (which is also your quote) as a parenthetical, so that it's Ralph doing the stabbing with the spear, snarling as he does so.

Comment: It's a nice answer and all, nicely presented. But do we need it? It draws the same conclusion. For a dubiously-topical question.

Comment: @DanBron Short answer: no.

Comment: Long answer: When I read the bare quote initially, I wasn't sure the sentence was well-formed. Then I wondered whether it was stabbing with the spear and (simultaneously) with the savage doubled up, whatever that meant. After I found out that it was a quote from a famous novel and got around to documenting this, I thought it was worth noting that the structure wasn't simply a list of 4 things post- semicolon as the other answer suggests. It was one action interrupted by a parenthetical and followed by the result. The OP didn't ask about the result, but the rest was interesting enough to note.

Comment: @Lawrence Thank you for clarifying in details. Appreciate it 